# How to display removed array_unique rows?

Tags: php, arrays

let's say I have this array:

```
Array => (
    0 => 'test',
    1 => 'test',
    2 => 'test2',
    3 => 'test3'
)
```

if I use `array_unique($array)` and var_dump the `$array` after it displays as (if I preserve keys):

```
Array => (
    0 => 'test',
    2 => 'test2',
    3 => 'test3'
)
```

but now my `1 => 'test'` row is lost and I can't display it (in the scenario of saying "these values are dupes").

I know I can do something like this (for single-level arrays):

```
function showArrayDupes($array)
{
    $dupes = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $item)
    {
        if (array_count_values($array)[$item] > 1) {
            $dupes[$key] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $dupes;
}
```

But this will show an array like this:

```
Array => (
    0 => 'test',
    1 => 'test'
)
```

I could use `array_unique` on $dupes but that will filter out the second occurrence, not the first.

Is there a native function in PHP that I don't know about that strips dupe rows in arrays and stores them into an array?

Comment: Stores both duplicate or just one?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya whatcha mean? :)

Comment: I know not of any native function that can help you achieve what you want to achieve but a couple of functions can be used to help you save the duplicate. Do you want to save both duplicates or just one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [array difference by key](http://php.net/array_diff_key):

```
$vals = ['test', 'test', 'test2', 'test3'];
$uniq = array_unique($vals);
$removed = array_diff_key($vals, $uniq);

echo 'Removed: ';
print_r($removed);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179757/discussion-on-answer-by-deceze-how-to-display-removed-array-unique-rows).